# How can we extract substring of the string by position and separator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

How can we divide the substring from the string

Like I have string

```
String mainString="///Trade Time///Trade Number///Amount Rs.///";
```

Now I have other string

```
String subString="Amount"
```

Then I want to extract the substring  `Amount Rs.` with the help of second string named **subString** not by any other method But it should be extracted through two parameters like  first is I have index no of Amount string and second is until the next string ///.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First get the index of the substring:

```
int startIndex = mainString.IndexOf(subString);
```

Then get the index of the following slashes:

```
int endIndex = mainString.IndexOf("///", startIndex);
```

Then you can get the substring that you want:

```
string amountString = mainString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

As a compliment to @Guffa's answer, you can make an extension method out of it:

*Note: There's no validation to ensure that the provided indexes are in the bounds of the string.*

```
public static class StringExtensions
{

    public static string SubstringBetweenIndexes(string value, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        return value.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem I believe:

```
mainString.substring(mainString.IndexOf("Amount Rs. "), "///")
```

where `mainString.IndexOf("Amount Rs. ")` is the *Start Index*
& `"///"` is the *End Index*.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = Regex.Match("///(?<String>[^/]*?" + subString + "[^/]*?)///").Groups["String"].Value;
```

Should use `String.Format` but the exact usage of `{x}` in an @ string win a Regex I can't remember (do you need to double up the `{}`?)

**N.B:** This assumes you are not expecting any `/`, so could be improved a little.

Comment: You have put an @ before the first string literal, so it would look for `\/\/\/` rather than `///`. Besides, `\/` is not a valid escape sequence. You should use the `Regex.Escape` method on the `subString` value that you put in the regular expression for it to be safe for any value.