# Get length of Substring from string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a following string `12 OT  14:51 2407 005  00:06 200        0009715008742      0`.Now i have broken this string into string array based on space with following code..

```
string[] arrUser = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Now i have to select these above `arrUser` elements.Now as per my requirement i have to get the array element location from the original string till it reaches the next character(word) in the string .For example..

```
If i have selected 12 it should be like (0,2)
If i have selected 14:51 it should be like (7,12)
```

How to get this .Please help me ..
Am sorry i am not able to describe it better .Not getting to desc.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: _If i have selected 14:51 it should be like (6,12)_. Shouldn't it be `(7,12)`?

Comment: Something around this would solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591130/how-can-we-extract-substring-of-the-string-by-position-and-separator

Comment: I think 14:51 should return 6,12 only as for 12 you are returning 0 the matching start index

Comment: @kishoreVM How to get the things programatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a number of ways, the easiest of which is probably just to use `string.IndexOf(string)`. You can just grab the index of the starting character, and you know the length from your input. That's that, then.

But if you want to be a bit more efficient (and fun--I'll admit that I answered this a bit just for the fun of it) about it, I'd probably just do it all in one pass. I haven't tested this, but it should do what you'd be looking for. Pretty simple.

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> SplitWithIndexes(string str, char splitChar)
{
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    int retStartIndex = 0;

    for (int v = 0; v < str.Length; v++)
    {
         char c = str[v];

         if (c == splitChar)
         {
             yield return new Tuple<string, int>(ret.ToString(), retStartIndex);
             ret.Clear();
             retStartIndex = v + 1;
         }
         else
         {
             ret.Append(c);
         }
    }

    yield return new Tuple<string, int>(ret.ToString(), retStartIndex);
}
```